VHDL process sensitivity list
This is a follow up question relating to VHDL multiple processes.
I have these four processes which don't give any output.
        Periode_end : process(counter)
        begin
            if(counter = FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX) then
                period_end <= '1';
            else
                period_end <= '0';
            end if;
        end process;

        Count_proc : process(Clk, Reset)
        begin
            if (Reset = '0') then
                if rising_edge(Clk) then
                    if ( period_end = '1') then
                        counter <= 0;
                    else
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                    end if;
                end if;
            else
                counter <= 0;  
            end if;
        end process;

        PWM_target_proc : process(Clk, Reset)
        begin
            if (Reset = '0') then
                if rising_edge(Clk) then
                    if ( period_end = '1') then
                        if (pwm_target = FREQ_PWM_COUNTER_MAX) then
                            pwm_target <= 0;
                            pwm_counter <= 0;
                        else
                            pwm_counter <= pwm_counter + 1;
                            pwm_target <= Pwm_counter*PWM_STEP;
                        end if;
                    end if;        
                end if;
            else
                pwm_target <= 0;
                pwm_counter <= 0;
            end if;
        end process;
        
        PWM_output : process(counter, pwm_target)
        begin 
            if (counter < pwm_target) then
                pwm_value <= '1';
                debug_value <= '1';
            else
                pwm_value <= '0';
                debug_value<= '0';
            end if;
        end process;

But the program will not execute anything on hardware. I have found that it has to do with how the Clk and Reset signal is handled inside the two processes.
This don't work
if (Reset = '0') then
    if rising_edge(Clk) then
    ....
    end if;
else
    ....
end if;

This work
if (Reset = '0') then
   ...
elsif rising_edge(Clk) then
   ...
end if; 

If I change the code with the "elsif" then it gives the desired output. I don't understand.

Synthesis tools must decide, where to implement flipflops. Therefore they look for special structures in the VHDL code. The structure containing "elsif" is a well known flipflop structure for synthesis tools. The other structure you are using is not well known and probably not correctly implemented by synthesis. You should look in the synthesis protocol, perhaps you will find warnings regarding this issue.

In the first construct, the reset condition (if Reset = '0') and the clock edge condition (if rising_edge(Clk)) are nested. This means that the rising edge of the clock is checked only if the reset condition is false.

@MatthiasSchweikart OK it is an explanation like that I am looking for. I know my implementation is properly a bit to traditional software like. Only got one warning: "Parallel synthesis criteria is not met"

@liaifat85 But is that a problem if I keep Reset = 1? I have tried and it don't work.


This doesn't work

Reset is active when not '0':
if (Reset = '0') then
    if rising_edge(Clk) then
    ....
    end if;
else
    ....
end if;


This works

Reset is active when '0':
if (Reset = '0') then
   ...
elsif rising_edge(Clk) then
   ...
end if; 

Was this inversion intended and have you used it in the tests?

Yes I see you point not the best code, but I have the Reset signal mapped to a slide switch so I can  hangs on the fly and there is no change, when I use the nested IF.
